# Can I set up two separate VPNs on servers connected to the same router?

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I am in a peculiar situation where a business has been split into two separate entities, but their infrastructure remains under the same roof.
All of our physical servers are connected to the same router. Currently, the router connects to the switch, we have WINDOWS SERVER A connected to it with VPN role configured.

Would it be possible to set up another VPN on WINDOWS SERVER B, connected to the same router, and have the two VPNs running simultaneously, forwarding user traffic to the appropriate WINDOWS SERVER?

I have asked our administrator but he thinks that port forwarding would be the issue.

Sketch:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The VPNs would need to use different ports on the exterior to get traffic routed to the correct VPN server, but I think the bigger problem is what happens after the tunnel is established. do you expect users to be able to access servers other than the VPN server on the network (but not just any server on the network)? if so, you'll have to do that with firewalls, because if you configure the VPN clients to be able to connect to systems on the network through the VPN, they would by default be able to access all of them.

Comment: What VPN protocol are you using? Regarding ports specifically, the answer could be "yes" for some protocols (e.g. OpenVPN), but a hard "no" for other protocols (e.g. IPsec or PPTP).

Answer (score 0):

Yes but...

This so.ewhat depends on things not disclosed in your question.

- If Server A and B have each have globally reachable IP addresses this should be fine.
- If the router server A and B has multiple world accessible IP addresses and can map these to the Servers this can be done.
- Likewise if the VPNs use different protocols or ports - even if bith servers are behind NAT you should be able to make this work - so OpenVPN can ve used, or 2 other vpn protocols.

If none of the above are true you likely have an issue.  You may be able to work arround it by having the router act as a VPN instead, amd routing traffic differently (eg by assigning IP addresses in different subnets) based on login credentials.